# Python dataframe group by index level rather than index names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm having a multi-indexed dataframe. I understand that groupby(level=0) means groupby the first index, then how can I group the data by the first two indices using this method?
I tried groupby(level=0 and 1), and it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use list like:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1])
```

Also if want use aggregate function like `sum`, `mean`, `max`, `min`:

```
df.groupby(level=[0,1]).sum()
```

is possible simplify to:

```
df.sum(level=[0,1])
```